# Strange behavior grep -rnw

Tags: grep

I am using grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD in MacOS and I have found the following behavior.

I have two *.tex files. Each one of these contains the following lines

```
$k$-th bit of
$(i-m)$-th bit of
```

respectively. When I ran

```
grep --color -rnw . -e '\$-th bit of' --include="*.tex"
```

I got only the second file, i.e., $(i-m)$-th bit of, while I expect the two lines. Could you help me please to understand this behavior?

Comment: You should consider providing feedback to your questions by accepting or upvoting the answers. From your history of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6762037/juan-del-carmen-grados-v%C3%A1squez?tab=questions), I don't see it ever occurred. Remember accepting or doing an upvote is this site's way of saying a 'Thank You'

Answer (score 1):

Never use `-r` or `--include` or any other grep option to find files. The GNU guys really screwed up by adding those options to grep when there's a perfectly good tool named `find` for **find**ing files and now they've turned grep into a convoluted mush of finding files and Globally matching a Regular Expression within a file and Printing the result (`G/RE/P`).

Keep it simple - **find** the files with `find` then **g/re/p** within then using `grep`:

```
find . -name '*.tex' -exec grep --color -n '\$-th bit of' {} +
```

As others pointed out your `g/re/p` problem was the `-w` arg so I've removed that above.

Comment: I would be interested in a more in-depth discussion about the difference. Would it be to correct to think that `find ... -exec` forks for every file found, while `grep -r` is just the one? I'm aware that `find` has some heavy optimizations, so maybe it weighs out the cost of forking..

Comment: Josh - I've no idea how `grep -r` behaves but the find command in my answer  calls grep on batches on files (that's what the `+` at the end does) rather than individual files (change `+` to `\;` if you want it to grep 1 file at a time). I'm no expert on what tools fork when but I'd expect the performance difference between `find -exec grep` and `grep -r` to be negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I didn't know that! That makes sense though and would likely be a performance improvement across a wide search area. Maybe I'll peek at `grep`'s source code one day when I'm bored. I'm mainly curious about performance because while working on a legacy system, I've seen a difference of up to a minute with different implementations.

Comment: Sounds good and do let me know if they're planning to implement `sort` or `curl` or any other tools functionality within `grep` since they apparently thought including `find`s functionality was a great idea so who knows what else they have up their sleeves :-)!

Comment: I would say that `grep -r` is one of the most-used commands by software devs. While find is a tool better-suited to finding files, it involves a lot more typing to use `find . -exec grep`.

Comment: I doubt if `grep -r` is used much as a glance at its synopsis and examples of commands that use it should make any experienced UNIX developers skin crawl since it's so clearly counter to the UNIX philosophy of every command doing one thing and doing it well, and nether a `grep -r` nor a `find . -exec grep` command can be lengthy by their nature so the relative amount of typing of each doesn't matter. It's not like one's 2 lines and the others 20 - we're talking a handful of characters vs a sometimes slightly larger handful of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same version of grep.

It is caused by your use of the `-w` option:

```
 -w, --word-regexp
         The expression is searched for as a word (as if surrounded by `[[:<:]]' and `[[:>:]]'; see re_format(7)).
```

The matched part of the string `$k$-th bit of` is bounded on the left-hand side by a word character (i.e. `k`) so the match is treated as being inside a "word" and it can't therefore satisfy the "searched for as a whole word" requirement.

Try without `-w` and it will work fine.